# Moving to Netherlands. Job required documents

Tags: netherlands, relocation, job-hunting

My husband was invited to move to the Netherlands to work as IT specialist. We are moving with him (me and 2-year old son). I need to know what documents are required to be translated/apostilled/ notarially confirmed for me to be able to find a job? We are from Russia.
Thank you.

Comment: which company invites him? usually, they help with paper work. maybe you forgot to ask them, but they should of course know it themselves

Comment: Hello  Eugen. Of course the company helps. It's Rocket Software Inc. But I ask for myself,because i hope i could find the job too.

Comment: That are two separate things. You should have a permit to live and work in NL. When you moved with your husband, you have both of them, and I posted documents that we needed to accomplish moving. For finding a job, you must have a permit to work in NL. No needs for any other documents unless you're doing some science research or strictly regulated jobs like doctors, lawyers, etc. Some companies ask for diploma translated, but you can do it yourself, no notarial or apostil on it required

Answer (score 2):

The information you need starts at [this document](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/family/Pages/default.aspx) at the Dutch Immigration and Naturalisation service.

> Family
>
> You wish to stay in the Netherlands to stay with a family member for more than 90 days.
>
> It is possible to join your family member in the Netherlands when you are married or are in a registered partnership, when you wish to stay with your unmarried partner or as a minor child to stay with your parent(s).
>
> Stay with your spouse or registered partner
>   Stay with your unmarried partner
>   Minor child to stay with your parent(s)
>   Child born in the Netherlands

The links leading from the 1st and 4th sections apply to you, but is far too much information to quote here.

And as Eugen commented, the company may be able to help you out; they may know what is required for wives and children of their foreign employees.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have children so that the papers list might be slightly different. We are from Ukraine, but I think there should not be much difference for Russian people.

You don't need any document to find a job. You need be visa to have on-site interview if it is required.

When job offer is secured and contract is signed. Then also to getting working permit you need:

1. Birth certificate translated and apostilled
2. Marriage certificate translated and apostilled

I assume you need birth certificate for child as well, but it is better to ask IND.

Comment: Once she has a residence permit, though, she won't need a separate visa for on-site interviews.

Comment: Thank you. Soon we are going to the embassy. Marriage cert and birth cert for the child is translated and appostilled,but the attorney didn't ask us to prepare our birth cert. But a lot of people in forums said it's necessary.